# Making C# library using native Windows API

Tags: c#, dll, dllimport

I am building C# library (.dll), where some classes use native Windows API functions. To be specific, functions `GetPrivateProfileString` and `WritePrivateProfileString`, like:

```
static class NativeMethods
{
    // external functions for working with ini files
    [DllImport("kernel32.DLL", EntryPoint = "GetPrivateProfileStringW",
      SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, ExactSpelling = true,
      CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public static extern int GetPrivateProfileString(string lpAppName, string lpKeyName,
      string lpDefault,
      string lpReturnString,
      int nSize,
      string lpFilename);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern bool WritePrivateProfileString(string lpAppName,
                                                        string lpKeyName,
                                                        string lpString,
                                                        string lpFileName);
}
```

And using them:

```
NativeMethods.GetPrivateProfileString(section, key, "", result, 127, this.path);
NativeMethods.WritePrivateProfileString(section, key, " " + value, this.path);
```

When I am using this class directly in another project (without using it from dll), it works without problem. But when I build it into dll, then reference this dll in another project, then these functions aren't working. They simply do nothing.

Comment: I have code that does just that, but it works fine. One difference I can see however is that I use a `StringBuilder` to return the result from `GetPrivateProfileString`. I don't think it will make any difference though... `static extern int GetPrivateProfileString(string section, string key, string defaultValue, StringBuilder result, int size, string fileName);`

Comment: Have you tried debugging into the code to see if there's an error being returned?

Comment: It shouldn't have such effect. As I say, this code works normally if I've used it directly as included into the project. But no when using it from reference dll library.

Comment: @Matthew: Unfortunately, no error. It goes over method call, but method does nothing.

Comment: Does it return `0`? If so have you called `Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()` to see what the error is?

Answer (score 1):

Your pinvoke for `GetPrivateProfileString` is wrong as Matthew says. You need to use `StringBuilder` when passing string data back to the caller.

You are not checking for errors. So it's entirely plausible that the functions are failing without you knowing that.

In order to know why your calls are failing you'd first need to fix these issues. Then you can look at the return values. Knowledge also of the values of the parameters that you are using would help. But only you have the ability to do that, at present.

The bigger problem is that you are not meant to call these functions at all. The [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724353.aspx) says:

> This function is provided only for compatibility with 16-bit Windows-based applications.

These functions contain numerous compatibility shims that make using them a complete minefield. Don't go there. Find a decent third party native C~ ini file class and pretend you never heard of `GetPrivateProfileString` and `WritePrivateProfileString`.

Comment: I have modified to use StringBuilder, and I'm checking return value now. Again, method is processed, with return value  = 0. Or can I check errors while running DLLImported methods?

Comment: Return value of 0 means failure, for both functions. As described in the documentation. Have you read the documentation in detail yet? Actually I urge you not to even bother doing that. Please stop using them. As MS instructs.

Comment: @Majak The return value is `the number of characters copied to the buffer, not including the terminating null character.`

Comment: I've found solution. But thanks for your suggestions guys. I'll try to find some good quality 3rd party INI parser library.

Answer (score 0):

Oh, I found error. I forced to find ini file path in current directory (in my DLL class code). As I call it from DLL, it was automatically looking for file in *C:\Windows*. After using `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + iniFile` , it works.

Comment: Use `Path.Combine` to join paths.